# Total Time reports with XtraScheduler control

Tags: devexpress

Is any easy way to make "total time" reports with  XtraScheduler control.
I need couple reports that will calculate total time by day/week/month for each resorce and appointment type.

Is posible to do this with XtraSchedulerReport or I must calculate this manualy?

Answer (score 4):

There aren't any built in functions to calculate the total time by resource and appointment type, but it's definitely possible to do this using XtraScheduler. Check out the two following examples for better details on how:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E977.aspx

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E121.aspx

:)

Also, try something like this:

```
    internal static TimeIntervalCollectionEx CalculateBusyTime(AppointmentBaseCollection appointments, TimeInterval interval) {

        TimeIntervalCollectionEx busyIntervals = new TimeIntervalCollectionEx();

        int count = appointments.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)

            busyIntervals.Add(TimeInterval.Intersect(interval, appointments[i].CreateInterval()));

        return busyIntervals;

    }
```